# Parsing downlink cellular towers signals

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, sc-fdma

I want to parse signals coming from 4G/5G towers to extract only the ID of the tower and the transmission time (on simplex communication: only downlink). Are these packets (or frames) sent on a regular time interval ?

Comment: Have you downloaded the applicable standards and studied them?  Chances are, yes.  But that's all in detail in the documents, and while you usually have to pay big bucks for official copies of the standard, you can also usually get your hands on draft copies for free.

Comment: Hi! not a trivial project, I'd recommend you start with a working open source receiver and understand that. As asked, it's really not clear where from detection to synchronization to OFDM reception to channel decoding to data handling you're actually stuck, and if the question is "how to build an LTE receiver", I think that's a bit broad.

Comment: The answer is Yes.

Comment: thank you for your answers. @MarcusMüller yes I need to build an LTE/NR receiver, but before starting such implementation I wanted to be sure that the time stamp is sent on a regular time interval

Comment: @afousafous again, you don't need to build an NR receiver from scratch. That takes companies full of experts years. You need to learn what is there and build upon that.

Comment: @afousafous this starts with the fact that most NR networks have "classical" non-NR (4G) radio as organizational layer and only do the payload data transport on NR; standalone-5G is pretty rare. Feel free to look at software like srsLTE/srsUE and openLTE to see how the 4G receiving end is implemented.

Comment: @MarcusMüller We are rolling out 5G SA (Standalone) in the US. I am not sure about Europe, maybe the last semester of next year. However, as the baseband processing is pretty much the same thing between 4G LTE and 5G NR, you are right that the OP can look at LTE open sources.

Comment: @AlexTP cool! I didn't realize we've come this far! May I guess this is the 600 MHz band?

Comment: @afousafous if you have access to MATLAB Toolbox, there are many examples, in both link and system levels, that are very easy to follow. Otherwise, I would suggest [OpenAirInterface](https://openairinterface.org/) that is more complete and updated.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, 600MHz and 2500MHz (TMO). If I remember correctly, Verizon and AT&T are currently NSA.

Comment: @AlexTP so (as usual) my MNO will be T-Mobile next time I travel to the US :) Some things deserve to be fostered.

Comment: thank you all for your answers